# Why is this code for getting a two-digit month number not working?

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to produce a line item ID by turning the date (in cell `A2`, formatted as YYYY-MM-DD) into a six-digit date followed by a sequential identifier - the end result for the fourth edit made today, for instance, would be `151209-4`.

The date is in `A2`, the sequence number is in `B2`.

I've tried `=MONTH(A2)` on its own, and it returns the right month. However, as soon as I try to use `=TEXT(MONTH(A2),"mm")` or any variation of it, it just keeps spitting out January.

The full function I'm using is

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",CONCATENATE(RIGHT(YEAR(A2),2), TEXT(MONTH(A2),"mm"), TEXT(DAY(A2),"dd"), "-", B2))
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2,"yy"),TEXT(A2,"mm"),TEXT(A2,"dd"),"-",B2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",CONCATENATE(TEXT(A2,"yy"&"mm"&"dd"),"-",B2))
```